# HTML 5 Canvas drawing a straight smooth line example?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I got this canvas drawing app example and I need help understanding certain parts of the code. The app draws a really smooth line just like a pen drawing tool.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var radius = 10;
var dragging = false;


canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
context.lineWidth = radius*2;

var putPoint = function(e){
  if(dragging){
    context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    context.stroke();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    context.fill();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }
}

var engage = function(e){
  dragging = true;
  putPoint(e);
}

var disengage = function(){
  dragging = false;
  context.beginPath();
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Canvas</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0">
  <canvas style="display:block;" id="canvas">
    sorry this browser does not support HTML 5 Canvas!
  </canvas>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to draw attention to this part of the JS code which I am having trouble understanding:

```
var putPoint = function(e){
  if(dragging){
    context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    context.stroke();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    context.fill();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }
}
```

I just don't understand how parts of that code relate to each other and ultimately creates a really smooth line.

Breaking that code down:

```
context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
context.stroke();
```

This piece of code is straightforward as it connects the previous coordinate with a line. However the line is not smooth and looks rough.

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
context.fill();
```

This part just prints a circle but if I move my mouse really quickly the circles don't connect to each other.

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
```

This is the final part of the code that makes drawing a line really smooth and efficient. This part of the code I don't understand and how it relates in any way.

Please explain the code logic behind the whole function and how it relates to each.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept in that function is simple: to draw a "smooth" line you basically have to first draw a normal "rough" line, and then end it with a circle.

Breaking it down, you are doing this:

1. Draw a "rough" line:

   ```
   context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
   context.stroke();
   ```

   Which would look like this:

   [image: line]
2. Add a circle to make the line "smooth":

   ```
   context.beginPath();
   context.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
   context.fill();
   ```

   Which transforms the previous line in something like this:

   [image: smooth line]

   Here you might wonder: you said "*end* it with a circle", so why is there a circle at the beginning of the line? Well, actually there are way more circles. Every time the function is called, the line is drawn from the previous known position of the mouse to the next one, so at the beginning the line is drawn with a length of zero, and a circle is made. Then the mouse continues moving, and more very small segments are added with circles at the end of them. Drawing down all those (almost infinite) small segments ending with circles creates a nice straight line.

   This also means that the smoothness of the line only depends on the resolution at which it's drawn. The more times per second the function is called and the slower the mouse goes, the smoother the line will be.
3. Move the current position of the path to the mouse position

   ```
   context.beginPath();
   context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
   ```

   These two lines just make sure the next time the function is called, the beginning point will already be set.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and I understand it much more now.  Just one question regarding 3.0 in your answer. I don't understand why it is needed as the line in 2.0 looks already smooth? Thanks

Comment: @jdogdvr about the 3rd point: those two lines set the new path (for the next segment to be drawn) to begin at the current position of the mouse. So as long as you are drawing the position gets updated over and over again to draw the segments.

Comment: Ok, although wouldn't  lineTo(x,y) at the start of the function establish the clients coordinates? For example if the function got called 2 times then it would draw a line from A to B. I notice without the code in 3.0 the circles are abnormally larger and moving the mouse quickly only prints a few circles. I just don't get it...

Comment: Think about it: you have to draw a segment in your function that goes from the previous position to the current position of the mouse. The lineTo(x, y) function draws from where you left (last move command) to the coordinates x y, but where did you left? You set that at the end of the function using moveTo(client.x, client.y), so the next time the function gets called the line is drawn from the previous position of the mouse (old client.x and client.y) to the current one (new client.x and client.y). It's just a little trick for not having to save the position of the mouse in a global variable.